# How to insert numeric columns in an Azure Storage Table?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

When I try to insert a row with a numeric value in one column, the insertion fails.
**The next example works when transforming the number to a string with `msg.registryTimestamp.toString()`**.

The Azure Function Documentation for the [Azure Storage Table Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table?tabs=javascript) does not mention anything about how to define the schema or how to insert different types of columns or whatever.

This is the output definition, where `msg.registryTimestamp` is numeric:

```js
    context.bindings.registry = [];
    context.bindings.registry.push({
        PartitionKey : msg.eventId,
        RowKey : msg.id,
        registryTimestamp: msg.registryTimestamp
    });
```

This is the function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "tableName": "Registry",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "name": "registry",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: On my side it is no problem. Maybe there is something wrong with your other code? Or can you show the error details?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my side, insert numeric columns is no problem, this is my code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var msg = new Object();
    msg.registryTimestamp = 222
    context.bindings.tableBinding = [];
    context.bindings.tableBinding.push({
        PartitionKey: "rtbhtrehtre",
        RowKey: "afwegfergrweg",
        registryTimestamp: msg.registryTimestamp
    });

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};
```

And this is my function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tableName": "MyTable",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "name": "tableBinding",
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

After trigger, I can insert the data:

[image]

[image]

Maybe there is some error with your other code, can you show that?

Comment: You are right. No problem at all in the insertion. But I don't know what generated the error. Refactoring fixed the problem.